# JS Jquery .Find .Each to create indiviual strings for use creating a BLOB later on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this snippet of a XML file

```
<guests>
<guest firstName="Donald" lastName="Duck" title="MR" age="50">
</guests>
<guests>
<guest firstName="Daisy" lastName="Duck" title="MRS" ageRange="52"/>
</guests>
<guests>
<guest firstName="Huey," lastName="Duck" title="MR" ageRange="5"/>
<guest firstName="Dewey," lastName="Duck" title="MR" ageRange="5"/>
<guest firstName="Louie" lastName="Duck" title="MR" ageRange="5"/>
</guests>
<guests>
<guest firstName="Della" lastName="Duck" title="MRS" ageRange="30"/>
<guest firstName="Dudly " lastName="Dupont" title="MRS" ageRange="25"/>
<guest firstName="Dugan" lastName="Dupont" title="MST" ageRange="4"/>
</guests>
```

and I am cycling though it with this code

```
NoOfRooms = $(this).find("room").length; 
 $(this).find('guests').each(function () {  
    $(this).find('guest').each(function () {
        GSTFName = $(this).attr("firstName"),
        GSTLName = $(this).attr("lastName"),
        GSTtitle = $(this).attr("title"),
        GSTAge = $(this).attr("age");

        GSTFullName = (GSTtitle + " " + GSTFName + " " + GSTLName);

        GSTString = [GSTFullName, GSTAge].join(",");

        console.log("Guests name are ", GSTString);
    });
 });
```

and the moment, the output I am getting in Console is

```
Guests name are  MR Donald Duck,50
Guests name are  MRS Daisy Duck,52
Guests name are  MR Huey Duck,5
Guests name are  MR Dewey Duck,5
Guests name are  MR Louie Duck,5
```

etc

What I'm trying to get is all the **guest** in each **guests** node, ie:

```
Guests name are  MR Donald Duck,50
Guests name are  MRS Daisy Duck,52
Guests name are  MR Huey Duck,5,Dewey Duck,5,MR Louie Duck,5
```

etc, but in there own strings to I can reference them later when creating a Blob
... something like

```
    for (var stay = 0; stay < xNoOfRooms ; stay ++) { 
    DLoadFile = new Blob([CSV, (AllRmString), GSTString(stay)], { type: contentType });
}
```

as you can (hopefully) see, I am part of they way..... could someone help me get the rest of the way ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use `map()` instead of `each` on the inner loop to create array...then join array when inner loop is done

```
$(this).find('guests').each(function() {

  var guests = $(this).find('guest').map(function() {
    var GSTFName = $(this).attr("firstName"),
      GSTLName = $(this).attr("lastName"),
      GSTtitle = $(this).attr("title"),
      GSTAge = $(this).attr("age"),
      GSTFullName = (GSTtitle + " " + GSTFName + " " + GSTLName);

    return [GSTFullName, GSTAge].join(",");      
  }).get();

  console.log("Guests name are ", guests.join());
});
```

Comment: Hi charlietfl , THANK YOU. adding `guestsdata = guests.join();` after the `GET` allows me to save the data into a string, for reference later.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = "";
$(this).find('guest').each(function () {
    GSTFName = $(this).attr("firstName"),
    GSTLName = $(this).attr("lastName"),
    GSTtitle = $(this).attr("title"),
    GSTAge = $(this).attr("age");

    GSTFullName = (GSTtitle + " " + GSTFName + " " + GSTLName);

    GSTString = [GSTFullName, GSTAge].join(",");
    result+=","+GSTString;
});

console.log("Guests name are ", result);
```

Simply concatenate one string in the inner loop, then display it if the inner loop finished.